# Migrate Lucene from java 1.8 to 1.6 Path FSDirectory

Tags: java, lucene

I have a working application on java 1.8, but I have to change this in java 1.6 because there are no:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

> Path path = Paths.get(indexLocation);   Directory index =
>   FSDirectory.open(path);

I found old code example there was

> Directory index=FSDirectory.open(new File(indexLocation));

But now `.open()` needs Path as parameter. How to resolve this?

Comment: what do you get if you execute System.out.println(indexLocation);

Comment: ah indexLocation its simple String like "C:/indexes"

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this backport? Couldn't you just use an old version of lucene if you're using an old version of java? I'd suggest version 4.7 would be the best place to start based on [this post](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/general/225300).

Comment: To fix your new error you're going to have to change the method signature of `FSDirectory.open()` to not take in a `File` instead of a `Path`, and then you'll have to change the code that uses that parameter, and then you'll have to change the next thing... Before you know it you'll have reverted all the commits that use Java 7 features since March 2014. And you're then relying on _your_ code, not the widely used, tested and trusted original code.

Comment: Yes I can try use old version if as there will be no solution. At first trying make it on Lucene 5.2.1. I have to integrate Lucene search with application builded on java 1.6.Already this part of code it's only difference between java 6 and 8

Comment: Ok, well [here's the changelog](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/changes/Changes.html#v4.8.0.system_requirements) showing just how many releases worth of changes you'll have to check for any dependencies on or assumptions about Java 7. 4.7.2 seems to be the specific last Java 6 version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have java 6 you must use Lucene library version < 4.8.

From Lucene 4.8, java 7 is required. This is the link of the system requirements: [lucene 4.8 change log](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/changes/Changes.html#v4.8.0.system_requirements)